# Ruby Arrays with similar entries

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays

```
Device = ["Washington DC","Newyork","San Diego","Florida"]

Device1 = ["Washington DC","Newyork","San Diego","Florida"]
```

when I do this to delete spaces from elements of one of the arrays

```
Device.each do |x|
  x.gsub!(' ','')
  puts x
end
```

spaces from elements of other array also been deleted. When I do puts for both arrays this is what I am getting

```
["WashingtonDC","Newyork","SanDiego","Florida"]
["WashingtonDC","Newyork","SanDiego","Florida"]
```

Please tell me what wrong I am doing or what should I do to delete spaces from one of the array's elements only

Comment: What is wrong with that? You tell us, not we telling you.

Comment: Instead of `gsub` you can use `delete(' ')`

Comment: Please post the actual code next time as the example provided will not produce the result provided.

Comment: @engineersmnky Sure..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have assigned same `value` to the different `variables` like below:

```
device = ["Washington DC","Newyork","San Diego","Florida"]
device1 = ["Washington DC","Newyork","San Diego","Florida"]
```

then your below code **definitely** **works fine**:

```
device.each do |x|
  x.gsub!(' ','')
  puts x
end
```

after executing above code, your variables looks like:

```
> device
#=> ["WashingtonDC", "Newyork", "SanDiego", "Florida"] 
> device1
#=> ["Washington DC", "Newyork", "San Diego", "Florida"]
```

**BUT**

if you assigned some value to `variable` through `variable` then each variables contains same object.

```
> array = ["Washington DC","Newyork","San Diego","Florida"]
#=> ["Washington DC", "Newyork", "San Diego", "Florida"] 
> device = array
> device1 = array
> array.object_id
#=> 8031080 
> device.object_id
#=> 8031080 
> device1.object_id
#=> 8031080
```

so when you perform any action on any variable like `array`, `device` or `device1` it will reflects all variables.

You need to make duplicate copy of object. can assign like:

```
> array = ["Washington DC","Newyork","San Diego","Florida"]
> device = array.dup
> device1 = array.dup

> array.object_id
#=> 7077120 
> device.object_id
#=> 7005100 
> device1.object_id
#=> 6977660
```

I hope now this simple answer makes you clear and easy understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your arrays do not contain different strings but *references* to the same string object. When you modify one, then you modify all occurences.

```
string = "a reference"
array_1 = [string]
array_2 = [string]

array_1[0].gsub!(" ", "")

puts array_1 #> areference
puts array_2 #> areference
```

this is because you have a reference to the same string object in both arrays and you modify it inplace

```
puts array_1[0].object_id == array_2[0].object_id #> true
```

Try out following to see the difference

```
string_1 = "now it works"
array_1 = [string_1]
string_2 = "now it works"
array_2 =[string_2]

array_1[0].gsub!(" ", "")
puts array_1 #> nowitworks
puts array_2 #> now it works
```

You could also cretae a new array and leave the original array and the object it contains unchanged:

```
array_1 = ["hey there"]
array_1_no_spaces = array_1.map do |string|
  string.gsub(" ", "") # just gsub, not gsub!
end
```

A note on your code: please follow the best practices and name your variables in lower snake-case-case:

```
device
list_of_something
...
```

CamelCase style is used for classes:

```
class Device
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot It worked...also thanks for your suggestions on best practices I will take care:))